# Welding electrode diameter suggestion?

Tags: welding

I am just starting out welding. The job is to fillet weld 2"x1" 16 gauge (1.2mm) Rectangular Mild Steel Tubing for fabricating a frame. I have a 250 Amp DC welding machine. Can you suggest Electrode diameter and current? I currently have 8mm electrodes. Would they work fine if I used a low enough amperage setting?

Comment: What welding process?

Answer (score 5):

In my humble opinion, 8mm rods are way to big for 16 gauge mild steel. You'd need about 250 Amp for that size rod and you'd melt your stock. I wouldn't use a rod any bigger than 1/8". You'd need 50 to 90 Amps for that size rod. A 6013 welding rod should work fine and it's good for ac and dc welders.

Since you're a beginning welder, practice on a few pieces of scrap stock just to get the feel of a smaller rod.

Comment: Heck, 1/16" rods are commonly available. Or perhaps the OP would be looking for 1.5mm rods as the metric equivalent. Swatting a fly with a sledgehammer....

Comment: So, ideally, should I be using a 1/16" rod? Also, can you guys recommend a reference/table which mentions the recommended electrode sizes for various typical stock sizes.

Comment: @afterburner77  I can't really recommend a reference table but there are many of them available on the net or where you get your rods from.  A 1/16"  would be fine too. A lot of this depends on individual technique.  I once did a job on an overhead crane and started out with  1/4" rods  and finished it with 1/8" ...  just took a slower pace.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest going to MIG, much easier for a new welder ( or a crappy old welder ). Your thin stock would be a challenge for an experienced welder with stick ( SMA ) and any size electrodes and reverse polarity.